# Error in moving dataset value into labelbox control using vb.net

Tags: mysql, label, type-conversion, vb.net-2010

Am using web application in vb.net.Backend am using mysql. Writing procedure in mysql. am calling that procedure in vb.net. am getting value in dataset. But am getting error in moving values from dataset to label box control using vb.net

```
mysql (procedure)
-----------------
DELIMITER $$

CREATE  PROCEDURE pro_Datecal()
begin
SELECT DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY) as promisetopay;
end
```

in vb.net

---

```
Dim dstwo As New DataSet1TableAdapters.pro_DatecalTableAdapter
Dim dttwo As DataSet1.pro_DatecalDataTable = dstwo.GetData()
Label21.Text = CStr(dttwo("promisetopay").ToString)

in dttwo am getting value like below

promisetopay

8/31/2012 12:00:00 AM

error(Conversion from string "promisetopay" to type 'Integer' is not valid.)
-----
error in moving this value to label control
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dttwo` is a dataset. try,

```
Label21.Text = dttwo("promisetopay").rows(0)(0).ToString
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
Label21.Text = dttwo.Rows(0).Item("promisetopay").ToString
```

Comment: am getting error like rows is not a member of DataSet1.pro_Datecalrow

Comment: `Label21.Text = dttwo.Rows(0).Item("promisetopay")` ah ok, try this one @sudha.s

Comment: .Sorry for the late reply.Working fine

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15946/discussion-between-sudha-s-and-john-woo)